# ui router change abstract parent url params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below is how the ui-router state provider has been set for our project. Showing below a part of it.

```
  $stateProvider
 .state('Parent', {
    url: '/mainpath/:Id',
    templateUrl: getViewUrl('Main.html'),
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main',
    abstract: true,
    resolve: { 

})
.state('Parent.Child', {
    templateUrl: getViewUrl('Child.Html'),
    controller: 'ChildController',
    controllerAs: 'child',
    url: '/child',
    requireADLogin: true
})
.state('Parent.Child1', {
    templateUrl: getViewUrl('Child1.Html'),
    controller: 'Child1Controller',
    controllerAs: 'child1',
    url: '/child1',
    requireADLogin: true
})
```

.....many more child state.
Parent Path Contains url as '/mainpath/:Id', the Id is part of the parent and based on this value parent runs a number of resolve before loading any of the child state(parent being abstract cannot be navigated to any which way).

The end URL looks like http://something/x.html/mainpath/124353534/child1, the final html contains top section which is parent and below section contains the child

```
<Html>
<Parent>
<Child>
</Child>
<Parent>
</Html>
```

On the Parent HTML there is a dropdown list to change the Id in the path '/mainpath/:Id'(this is the problem), this value in the dropdown is captured in the main controller (parent) and the current child state is reloaded with $state.go('passing the new ID cause child value will change based on this Id'). All works fine except that i am not able to change the Id value in the URL.

Can you guys please help with this.

Comment: got it working by updating the params when navigating to child state $state.go('childstate', {"Id" : new value}, 'reload : childstate');

Answer (score 0):

I would store the id's in a service, and inject this service to the different controllers that uses it.